# ¿Cómo puedo convertir mi entrada en input en una ecuación operable en Python?

Tags: python, matemáticas

Estoy haciendo un programa que permita calcular los valores de las raíces de una función por el método de Newton-Raphson para cualquier tipo de función, el problema es que la introducir mi ecuación como 'input' y tratar de evaluarla en un valor "x" me arroja el mensaje <'str' object is not callable>
¿Hay forma de que el input pueda operarse como si fuera una línea más de código?

Este es mi código que llevo por el momento:

'''

```
from sympy import sympify
from sympy import lambdify

from Testing_Derivada import Primera_derivada, Segunda_derivada


def Newton_Raphson(c, funcion, variable, x):
    cont = 0
    Derivada1 = Primera_derivada(funcion, variable)
    Derivada2 = Segunda_derivada(funcion, variable)

while True:
    x_previa = x 

    der1 = lambdify(variable, Derivada1)
    der2 = lambdify(variable, Derivada2)

    x = x_previa - (der1(x)/der2(x))
    y = lambdify(variable, funcion)
    fx = y(x)

    cont += 1

    print("It: {:02} - x: {:.10f} - f(x): {:.10f}".format(cont, x, fx))

    #if cont >= 20:
    if (abs(x-x_previa) <= c):
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("It: {:02} - x: {:.10f} - fx: {:.10f}".format(cont, x, fx))
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = float(input("Introduce una tolerancia de calculo: "))
    funcion = input("Introduce una función: ")
    variable = input("En función de que variable se realizará la derivada: ")
    x = float(input("Introduce un valor inicial de la variable: "))

resultado = Newton_Raphson(c, funcion, variable, x)
print(resultado)
```

'''

Finalmente mi codigo que involucra a las derivadas es el siguiente:

```
import sympy

def Primera_derivada(funcion, variable): 
    x = sympy.Symbol(variable)
    U = funcion
    derivada1 = sympy.diff(U, variable)
    return derivada1

def Segunda_derivada(funcion, variable):
    x = sympy.Symbol(variable)
    U = funcion 
    derivada2 = sympy.diff(U, variable, variable)
    return derivada2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    funcion = input("Introduce la función a derivar: ")
    variable = input("En función de que variable: ")
    #resultado = derivada(funcion, variable)
    resultados = [funcion, Primera_derivada(funcion, variable), Segunda_derivada(funcion, variable)]
    print(resultados)
    print(type(funcion))
```

Comment: Podrías poner el código de las funciones `Primera_derivada` y `Segunda_derivada` por favor?

Comment: Podrías poner el. Código completo? Esto para ver tmb como estas obteniendo el input y detalles extras.

Answer (score 0):

Sé que es tarde para resolverte la duda pero la solución esta en el mismo *sympy*:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

a=input("Cualquier cosa: ")

t=parse_expr(a)

print(t)# y te saldrá en codigo sympy.
```